# Java applet: AccessControlException again

Tags: java, applet

Yet again issue with privileges of signed applets.

I want my *self-signed applet* to delete a file from the local drive, but I get the exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
  (java.io.FilePermission /Users/me/tmp.txt delete)
```

Here I invoke the deletion:

```
    public void deleteFile( String path )
    {
        AccessController.doPrivileged( new Deleter( path ));
    }
```

and this class deletes the file:

```
class Deleter implements PrivilegedAction {
    public Deleter( String path ) {
        m_path = path;
    }

    public Object run()
    {
        File file = new File( m_path );
        file.delete();
        return null;
    }

    private String m_path;
};
```

HTML code is:

```
<APPLET CODE="HelloWorld.class" ARCHIVE="SignedHelloWorld.jar" WIDTH=600 HEIGHT=25>
<PARAM NAME="MAYSCRIPT" VALUE="true">
</APPLET>
```

**SOLVED:**

I needed to add the policy (under OS X):

```
cat >> ~/.java.policy

grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "delete";   
};
```

Comment: Do you understand why this is a security issue?

Comment: I don't understand why this is an issue for a signed applet

Comment: Fine, what's in your policy file?

Comment: Errr... no policy file, isn't that *alternative* to signing? (apparently no :)

Comment: Did you tell your browser to trust your self-signed certificate when it asked you?

Comment: @EJP: yup, trust, accept all, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant permissions, applets need a policy file. This defines what they can do to the users system. You can find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html).